# What causes a swap partition to be shown as `(deleted)` in `/proc/swaps`?

Tags: linux, swap, yocto

I have a system with a dedicated swap partition, running a custom distribution generated by Yocto.

On startup, during init, I can see the first swapon command successfully activating the swap space. A second swapon is sent, which subsequently fail (with a `swapon failed: Device or resource busy` since the swap partition has already been activated).

However, once fully started, I realised the swap space was not used by the system and is shown as deleted by `swapon --show` and `cat /proc/swaps`:

```
root@machine:~# swapon --show
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/mmcblk0p4 (deleted)                partition       1023996 0       -1
```

I wonder what causes the swap partition to be shown as deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(deleted)` appended to a file name output by the kernel is the standard behaviour for files which have been deleted (see [`d_path` in `fs/dcache.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/dcache.c#n3283) — it’s well-documented, you don’t need to read C).

In this case, it means the device node `/dev/mmcblk0p4` has been deleted for some reason. (This doesn’t mean that the partition itself has been removed, it’s just the device node.)

Comment: Thanks, but how come in a startup process a device node can be deleted? What kind of command should I be looking for? Can a rootfs re-mount cause this for example?

Comment: Yes, a re-mount could cause this, especially if `udev` isn’t re-triggered (assuming it’s used at all). A simple `rm` can remove a device node... However, I wouldn’t expect that to prevent the swap from being used.

Comment: So I found out what it was in the end. Udev ended up loading a cache, and overwriting everything in `/dev`.
I didn't need this functionality, so I just prevented it from happening.
Thanks for the details!